# Create a nested hash from ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to get a nested hash from a set of objects? I want to nest objects by Date and Hour

Basically I want to do something like:

```
Notification.all.group_by{ |notification| notification.created_at.to_date }.group_by{ |notification| notification.created_at.time.hour }
```

Is this at all possible? I would like to end up with a structure like

```
{date: {time: [objects], time: [objects]}, date: {time: [objects], time: [objects]} }
```

I want to do this to render a table comparing multiple datasets grouped by date/time (other suggestions to achieve this are welcome) I am trying to achieve a effect similar to [d3.nest()](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
result = Notification.all.group_by { |item|
  item.created_at.to_date
}.map { |date, notifications|
  [date, notifications.group_by { |item| item.created_at.to_time.hour }]
}
```

This will return an array of hashes, but you can convert it to a hash of hashes with `Hash[result]`, or with `result.to_h` if you're on Ruby 2.x.